# Raster package. library(raster) doesn't work

Tags: raster, installation

I just installed R on my PC. I installed raster package but when I do `library(raster)` it returns me that:

```
Errore: caricamento pacchetto o namespace fallito per ‘raster’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘terra’ 1.4-22 già caricato, ma >= 1.5.12 è richiesto
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this temporary problem (CRAN not compiling terra) is to install the development version of terra like this:

`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

And then install raster

`install.packages('raster')`

Comment: I did it, but still: clc00 <- raster("CLC2000ACC_V2018_20.tif")
Errore in raster("CLC2000ACC_V2018_20.tif") : 
  non trovo la funzione "raster"

Comment: first do `library(raster)` ?

Answer (score 1):

While installing package `raster`, when R prompts whether you would like to compile and install package from source, you have to click *yes*.

The `raster` package depends on another package named `terra`. This package can be installed in two ways: from a pre-compiled binary or from its source code. The pre-compiled binary is an older version compared to the source code. You can see the following in your R console, after you agree to *yes* in the prompt:

```
      There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
  terra 1.4-22 1.5-12              TRUE
```

Package `raster` needs the newer version 1.5-12 of the `terra` package, as you can see in the error message. So, you need to install from source.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
Then
install.packages(“raster”)